# Comparar 2 strings

Tags: java, array, string, eclipse

La idea es que tu pones por ejemplo A y me lo tiene que pasar a numero, mas que numero es el valor del indice del array donde tengo las letras,
pero no funciona.

```
//Varianles
        String[] letras  =  {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};
        int fila = 0;
        String columna = "";
        val1 = false;
            int col1 = -1;
            while (val1 != true) {

                System.out.print("Diga la columna (A-J): ");
                columna = (teclado.next());
                int col  = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                    if (letras[i].equals(columna)) {
                        col = i;
                    }
                }
                if (col1 == -1) {
                    System.out.println("Letra no valida");
                } else if (col1 > 10 || col1 < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Posicion no valida!");
                } else {
                    val1=true;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes una confusión en el uso de tus variables, tienes variables declaradas al inicio y dentro del `while`, lo cuál es lo que te ha confundido. A mí también me confundió y he tenido que debuggear tu programa.

Aquí tu código arreglado y funcionando (he comentado las líneas):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] letras = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
        //int fila = 0; Esta variable no la usas en ningún lado
        String columna = "";
        boolean val1 = false; // Aquí falto establecer el tipo de dato
        //int col1 = -1; Por qué tienes esto si también lo tienes dentro del while?
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in); // Falto esto también

        while (val1 != true) {

            System.out.print("Diga la columna (A-J): ");

            // Aquí tenías esto: (teclado.next());
            // Está mal escrito, lo he cambiado por esto:
            columna = teclado.next();
            int col = -1; // Tienes esto mismo declarado arriba, mejor usa este

            for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                if (letras[i].equals(columna)) {
                    col = i;
                }
            }

            // Aquí tenías otro error, estabas usando una variable equivocada
            // He cambiado la variable col1 (la que tienes declarada al inicio) por col (la que tienes declarada dentro del while
            if (col == -1) {
                System.out.println("Letra no valida");
            } else if (col > 10 || col < 0) {
                System.out.println("Posicion no valida!");
            } else {
                val1 = true;

                // He agregado esto para saber si la letra ha sido encontrada
                System.out.println("Letra encontrada en la posición " + col);
            }

        }

        teclado.close(); // Cerrar Scanner

    }

}
```

Evidencia de su funcionamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias :D